# No SIM card installed

Tags: sim

Okay, so long story short, my husband bent my iPhone 6. It isn't that bad, the wifi and everything still works, but it says there is no longer a SIM card installed and I have no service. So I can no longer receive/send text messages or calls. Is there any fix to this that I can do? I feel like I've tried everything. I pulled it out of the phone and it's not broken. This is very frustrating. Thanks!

Also, one more thing, I deleted Facebook and Facebook messenger and now it is no longer letting me reinstall it. It will install all other apps but those two. Everything is up to date as well.

Comment: I'd say your only option would be a repair shop, preferably an Apple Store.

Comment: Thank you. I was really hoping there would be another way. I did call them and I really don't want to end up paying 300 dollars haha.

Comment: My friend had an iPhone 4s and he had also the `no SIM card installed` problem. He made the SIM card a bit thicker by sticking multi layers of adhesive tape behind of the SIM! And then it worked!! But I won't recommend this solution because the different type of phone/SIM size and the most important cause is: It can harm your iPhone.

Comment: Try using any old sim card remover to take the sim card out of your iPhone and put it back in. Just search for sim card remover on Amazon.